# Error with returning a variable in java

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to deal with this error:

```
 exit status 1
 Main.java:18: error: method area in class Main cannot be applied to given 
 types; 
 String ara = area();            
 ^
 required: double,double
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 1 error
```

The purpose of my code is to find the area of a rectangle using two methods, returning the area variable, and carrying over variables from one method to the next.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Enter Length");
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    double L = input.nextDouble();
      Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Width:  ");
            double W = input.nextDouble();
               String ara = area();
                  System.out.println(ara);
     }
     public static String area(double L, double W) {
        double total = L*W;
           String ara = String.valueOf(total);
               return ara;
     }
     }
```

Thank you all in advance, pretty new to the site as a whole.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what *precisely* is unclear to you about that error message?

Comment: You might want to look into [code indenting conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) to make your code easier for yourself and others to read.

Comment: Yes, the way you indent code is highly unusual and not easy for others to read

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with 'returning a variable'. It has to do with supplying *arguments* to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass two doubles to your area method. In other words take
this

```
String ara = area();
```

and change to:

```
String ara = area(L,W);
```

Comment: Fixed that and it ran! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firslt,you need to pass two arguments to the area function which you didnt in line

```
String ara=area(L,W);
```

so this error is coming

```
required: double,double
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 1 error
```

its asking for two double's arguments. And so there  is a difference in actual argument which you pass via main() and formal argument which you receives at function area().

**optional:**
Secondly ,you can change the return type of function area() as double so that it could be sent directly to the main function and take it in some double and print it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is:

your area() get two parameters,

```
public static String area(double L, double W){
  //your code
}
```

but when you call area(), you didn't pass the arguments.

```
String ara = area();
```

**Solution is:**

```
String ara = area(L,W);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two arguments of type double to your area method. In other words take this

```
String ara = area();
```

and change to:

```
String ara = area(arg1, arg2);
```